# UniswapV3: Quoter functions quoteExactInput & quoteExactOutput works not as expected

Tags: web3.py, uniswap

The function QuoteExactInput gives me wrong results when I try to calculate the output amount for the following route: ('WETH', 3000, 'cDAI', 500, 'DAI')

It actually returns "85.86221207 DAI for 1 WETH" what is absolutly wrong.

The function QuoteExactOutput throws an error...

I don't understand it, as the code works perfect with the reverse route ('DAI', 500, 'cDAI', 3000, 'WETH').

Please copy and paste the code bellow and try it out:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from eth_abi.packed import encode_single_packed, encode_abi_packed
import json

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/1c74d7c6bf64453dadf097e9b1363763"))
w3.eth.handleRevert = True

quoter_contract_address = "0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6"

    
def load_abi(filename): 
    abi_file = open(filename)
    abi_json = abi_file.read()
    abi_file.close()
    abi = json.loads(abi_json)
    return abi
quoter_abi = load_abi('./abis/IQuoter.json')

quoter_contract =w3.eth.contract(address=w3.toChecksumAddress(quoter_contract_address), abi=quoter_abi)

weth_token = { 
    "address" : "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2", 
    "symbol" : "WETH", 
    "name" : "Wrapped Ether",
    "decimals" : 18 
    }
dai_token = { 
    "address" :"0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F", 
    "symbol" : "DAI", 
    "name" : "DAI", 
    "decimals" : 18 
    }
cdai_token = { 
    "address" : "0x5d3a536E4D6DbD6114cc1Ead35777bAB948E3643", 
    "symbol" : "cDAI", 
    "name" : "Compound DAI", 
    "decimals" : 8 
    }

#This works
print()
print("This works")

#Route: ('DAI', 500, 'cDAI', 3000, 'WETH')
route_types = ['address', 'uint24', 'address', 'uint24', 'address']
route_tuple = (str(dai_token["address"]), int(500), str(cdai_token["address"]), int(3000), str(weth_token["address"]))
route_str = (str(dai_token["symbol"]), int(500), str(cdai_token["symbol"]), int(3000), str(weth_token["symbol"]))

print(f"Route: {route_str} ")

#Test QuoteExactInput with 1 DAI Input
input_token_amount = int(1 * (10 ** int(dai_token["decimals"])))
       
route_encoded = encode_abi_packed(route_types, route_tuple)  

amount_out = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactInput(route_encoded, int(input_token_amount)).call()
amount_out = amount_out / (10 ** int(weth_token["decimals"]))

print("Output Amount: {:.8f} WETH for 1 DAI".format(amount_out))

#Test QuoteExactOutput with 1 DAI Output
output_token_amount = int(1 * (10 ** int(dai_token["decimals"])))
       
route_encoded = encode_abi_packed(route_types, route_tuple)  

amount_in = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactOutput(route_encoded, int(output_token_amount)).call()
amount_in = amount_in / (10 ** int(weth_token["decimals"]))

print("Input Amount: {:.8f} WETH for 1 DAI".format(amount_in))





print()
print("This cause error")

#Route: ('WETH', 3000, 'cDAI', 500, 'DAI')
route_types = ['address', 'uint24', 'address', 'uint24', 'address']
route_tuple = (str(weth_token["address"]), int(3000), str(cdai_token["address"]), int(500), str(dai_token["address"]))
route_str = (str(weth_token["symbol"]), int(3000), str(cdai_token["symbol"]), int(500), str(dai_token["symbol"]))

route_tuple = (str(weth_token["address"]), int(3000), str(cdai_token["address"]), int(500), str(dai_token["address"]))
route_str = (str(weth_token["symbol"]), int(3000), str(cdai_token["symbol"]), int(500), str(dai_token["symbol"]))

print(f"Route: {route_str} ")

#Test QuoteExactInput with 1 WETH Input
input_token_amount = int(1 * (10 ** int(weth_token["decimals"])))
       
route_encoded = encode_abi_packed(route_types, route_tuple)  

amount_out = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactInput(route_encoded, int(input_token_amount)).call()
amount_out = amount_out / (10 ** int(dai_token["decimals"]))

print("Output Amount: {:.8f} DAI for 1 WETH".format(amount_out))



#Test QuoteExactOutput with 1 WETH Output
output_token_amount = int(1 * (10 ** int(weth_token["decimals"])))
       
route_encoded = encode_abi_packed(route_types, route_tuple)  

amount_in = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactOutput(route_encoded, int(output_token_amount)).call()
amount_in = amount_in / (10 ** int(dai_token["decimals"]))

print("Input Amount: {:.8f} DAI for 1 WETH".format(amount_in))
```

Does anyone understand what the problem could be?

Comment: Hey why are you supplying ('DAI', 500, 'cDAI', 3000, 'WETH') 500, 3000 in the route as docs says that should be fee but I don't understand what is 500 and 3000 here ?

Comment: This is the pool fee, which you should provide with e4 decimals. So 500 use the pool with maker fee of 0,5% and 3000 use the pool with the maker fee of 3%.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the two results differ so much is because of the sliding point. There is a huge price fluctuation in the weth/cdai, especially when you want to exchange 1 eth

Answer (score 0):

Suffering the same here!

My function to encode:

```
    function encodePath(path, fees) {
        if (path.length != fees.length + 1) {
          throw new Error('path/fee lengths do not match')
        }
        
      
        let encoded = '0x'
        for (let i = 0; i < fees.length; i++) {
          // 20 byte encoding of the address
          encoded += String(path[i]).slice(2)
          // 3 byte encoding of the fee
          encoded += String(ethers.utils.hexlify(fees[i])).slice(2).padStart(6, '0')
        }
        // encode the final token
        encoded += path[path.length - 1].slice(2)
      
        return encoded.toLowerCase()
      }
```

Calling the exactInput:

```
export const quoteExactInput = async (amount: any, chainId: number, encoded: string) =>{
  try {
    const quoter = new ethers.Contract(
      QUOTER_ADDRESS[chainId],
      Quoter.abi,
      setProvider(chainId)
    )
    const result = await quoter.callStatic.quoteExactInput(encoded, amount)
    return {error: false, result: result}
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, 'for quoteExactInput')
    return {error: true, result: error}
  }
}

export const getSmallerPriceImpact = async (amount: any, chainId: number) => {
    let output = []
    // const data = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/router/0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6/0xD87Ba7A50B2E7E660f678A895E4B72E7CB4CCd9C/0x8eB105CFc7ec7ebF126586689683a9104E6ec91b/5')
    console.log(data, 'encodedArr')
      for(let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
        console.log(data.data[i].encoded, 'encoded')
        const result = await quoteExactInput(amount, chainId, data.data[i].encoded)
        output.push(result)
      }
    return output
}
```

My encoded:

```
0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6000bb807865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f000bb8d87ba7a50b2e7e660f678a895e4b72e7cb4ccd9c
```

The error i'm getting:

```
Error: call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string "Unexpected error" [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="quoteExactInput(bytes,uint256)", data="0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010556e6578706563746564206572726f7200000000000000000000000000000000", errorArgs=["Unexpected error"], errorName="Error", errorSignature="Error(string)", reason="Unexpected error", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:12074:19)
    at Logger.throwError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:12083:16)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:2963:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:8868:40)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:8552:24)
```

```
"call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string "Unexpected error" [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="quoteExactInput(bytes,uint256)", data="0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010556e6578706563746564206572726f7200000000000000000000000000000000", errorArgs=["Unexpected error"], errorName="Error", errorSignature="Error(string)", reason="Unexpected error", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)"
```

Any hint?